# react-native globally prompt user to enable wifi or cellular when network failed

Tags: react-native, axios, interceptor

I want to know how to prompt the user to enable wifi or cellular when network failed with axios globally.
I use axios interceptors for catching network error and I use NetInfo for detecting no internet connection but I dont know how to propmt user for enabling wifi or cellular?

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, function(error) {
  if (!error.status) {
    // network error

    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
      console.log(isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline');

      if(!isConnected)
      {
        // how to prompt user enable wifi or cellular 
        
        
      }

    });

  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an alternative way to inform the user that the device's connection is lost regardless of screen. 
My way is to listen for network status change in an component and update this status to reducer. If you use react-navigation, you can listen in an component connected with redux (eg.ReduxNavigation). In this way, every screen can show the network status lost and inform the user to check network connection.

**NeworkStatus.js**

```
class NetworkStatus extends Component {
 componentWillMount() {
  //For device's network status
  NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(data => {
    this.props.updateData({
      prop: "networkStatus",
      value: data
    });
  }); 
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  //Listener for device's network status
  NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
    "connectionChange",
    this.handleConnectivityChange
 );
 }

 handleConnectivityChange = change => {
  this.props.updateData({
    prop: "networkStatus",
    value: change
  });
 };

 render() {
    return null;
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{updateData})(NetworkStatus);
```

**ReduxNavigation.js**

```
class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <NetworkStatus />
    <AppNavigation/>
  </View>
  );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ return state});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation);
```

**Screen1.js**

```
class Screen1 extends Component {
   render(){
       return (
         <View>
            <Text>Home</Text>
            {this.props.networkStatus ? null : (
             <View>
               <Text>No Internet Connection</Text>
             </View>
             )}
         </View>
       );
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { networkStatus } = state.common; // common is reducer name
  return {networkStatus};
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Screen1);
```

This is the way I've done in my App. If the device has connection, nothing is shown. But, if it has no connection, user can see the network information. You can decide how to show and UI design for your screen. I hope it'll help you.

Comment: thank you bro, but my main problem is in prompting user to enable mobile data or wifi and I want to do it globally so I dont need to add its code to all of my components

Comment: welcome, bro. Sorry for that my answer can't help you. I just think that prompting user in axios interceptor when calling network request looks like strange to me. So, It's ok for me that I only show this nework status in some screens I want. Hope you'll find an answer.